# How to install tomcat maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, cxf, maven-archetype

I'm trying to run the basic CXF maven archetype.

I've just tried to install tomcat7-maven-plugin-2.2.jar manually using :

```
mvn -X install:install-file -Dfile=/tmp/path/tomcat7-maven-plugin-2.2.jar -DgroupId=org.apache.tomcat.maven -DartifactId=tomcat7-maven-plugin -Dversion=2.2 -Dpackaging=jar
```

which leads to :

```
[INFO] Installing /tmp/path/tomcat7-maven-plugin-2.2.jar to /home/userxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/maven/tomcat7-maven-plugin/2.2/tomcat7-maven-plugin-2.2.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: < 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jan 23 17:50:42 CET 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/179M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

BUT when I try to call it on my project via :

```
mvn clean install tomcat:run-war
```

It says :

```
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'tomcat'.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] The plugin '**org.codehaus.mojo**:tomcat-maven-plugin' does not exist or no valid version could be found
```

Would u have an idea why maven is looking for "org.codehaus.mojo" groupId instead of "org.apache.tomcat.maven" ?

I know it was hosted at "org.codehaus.mojo" before, so is it a bug ?

Should I install the plugin in this groupId ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I get it, the comment in the CXF archetype is wrong :

```
            <!-- mvn clean install tomcat:run-war to deploy
            Look for "Running war on http://xxx" and
            "Setting the server's publish address to be /yyy"
            in console output; WSDL browser address will be
            concatenation of the two: http://xxx/yyy?wsdl
            -->
```

It should say `mvn clean install **tomcat7**:run-war to deploy` to correspond to the plugin they use in this archetype.